# Rsync copies junk data when file is a sparse file instead of just returning some form or read IO error

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to work out why `rsync` behaves in the way it does, when compared to other 'simpler' commands like `cp`.

I have a test setup involving an AWS File gateway and an appropriate NFS share and S3 bucket. The file gateway allows access to data in an S3 bucket as if it were any 'normal' NFS mount.

In the background S3 is moving old data to Glacier but those files remain visible within the NFS mount in what I'm calling a 'sparse file' (ie metadata is there, but no actual data is - not sure if that's the correct term or not), so that process is transparent. I have setup S3 with a lambda function using the cloudwatch logs to automatically initiate glacier restores when a file is requested, but found to be in Glacier ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/automate-restore-of-archived-objects-through-aws-storage-gateway/) for details on that for the interested).

My issue / question related to the difference in behaviour between `rsync` and others like `cp`.

When I try to `cp` the files in the NFS mount to another location, if the file is in glacier (ie unreadable) it pretty much immediately comes back with an IO Error for the file, and exits. To me, that is a desirable behaviour.

However, if I run `rsync -rvhWP` it acts as if its actually transferring data, it creates a file at the destination with the correct file size etc.. but its just data of random 1's and 0's.. it does at the end of the transfer say `rsync: read errors mapping "<FILE PATH>": Input/output error (5)` then `WARNING: <FILE> failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).` and it tries again and again... but that's AFTER its transferred like 150GB of junk data into the destination, which is just left there and not removed.

Why does `rsync` do this? Is it expected (if undesirable) behaviour? Why does `cp` immediately report file IO error when `rsync` doesn't? Is there a way to stop this undesirable `rsync` behaviour?

You may say 'just use `cp` then' and that's a valid point, just a case that `rsync` provides progress data that can be tracked, and I feel `rsync` is more robust for transferring files from a network location.

Comment: Interesting problem. No answer for you (yet?). "_I feel rsync is more robust for transferring files from a network location_" if you're copying from an NFS mount then `rsync` sees this as a local-to-local copy and switches off most (all?) of its optimisations

Comment: "Sparse file", as I understand the term, is used for a file where blocks consisting only of zeroes are not actually allocated, and don't need space on the disk. The question really is how those "files with metadata but no data" are handled by the NFS, and I bet there is some assumption by rsync on how FS calls should behave that is violated by NFS (which already has interesting behaviour in edge cases without the "files with metadata but without data" thing). TL;DR: `rsync` needs the actual **data** of the file to decide if it should copy it or not. Without that, there'll be trouble.

Comment: Thanks both!! Some interesting points have been raised! I appreciate the time taken to comment! seems I've slightly stumbled on something interesting, if outside the 'norm'! If there is nothing to be done to stop the behaviour with `rsync` its not quite the end of the world, but would need a little ponder! (its the whole `cp` not giving any progress output, but there are ways around that I think)